# Google Chrome is Automatically restoring history

Tags: c#, sqlite, google-chrome, browser-history

I am trying to delete Chrome history from c# code with sqlite by using query

1. **delete from urls.**
2. **delete from visits.**

which are in history file present in `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and query are executing without any problem.

But does not reflect any change when I open the browser and go to history tab.

I have also tried by deleting the History file but history is getting restored in chrome automatically and the previous  history is available.

In Which file chrome store its history and from where its getting the deleted history?

If i delete the whole Default folder(`AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`) then i am able to delete history.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **chrome://settings/** And Change Sync Setting
And Go to **Google.com\history** And Remove Your history or disable history

Comment: Not able to find Sync Setting